# Inject listener interface into parent fragment from OnAttach

Tags: android, android-fragments, dagger-2, dagger

My Title of the question is my be wrong, but I don't know what to write. 
Currently, I am initializing a validateBasicListener in SignupMainFragment from onAttach of SignupBasicChildFragment, but Basically I want to Inject it with dagger2 but don't know how to do it, My Code is as follows,

```
public class SignupMainFragment extends DaggerFragment implements SignUPContract.View{

    @Inject
    SignUPContract.Presenter signUPPresenter;

   /* This is being initialized from SignupBasicChildFragment onAttach, 
    but   i want it to inject it with Dagger2, but don't know how 
   to do it. */
   public BasicSignUp validateBasicListener;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup, container, false);
    }

}
```

This is my Module for SignupMainFragment

```
public abstract class SignupModule {
@FragmentScoped
@Binds
abstract SignUPContract.Presenter signUpPresenter(SignUPPresenter presenter);

@FragmentScoped
@Binds
abstract SignUPContract.View signUpView(SignupMainFragment loginFragment);

@FragmentChildScoped
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = BasicModule.class)
abstract SignupBasicChildFragment signupBasicChildFragment();
}
```

This is my Another fragment where interface of SignupMainFragment is initialzed,

```
public class SignupBasicChildFragment extends DaggerFragment implements BasicContract.View{

@Inject
BasicContract.Presenter presenter;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    ((SignupMainFragment) getParentFragment()).validateBasicListener = this;  // I want to inject this with dagger 2
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child_signupbasic, container, false);
 }

 }
```

Module for Above,

```
@Module
public abstract class BasicModule {
@FragmentChildScoped
@Binds
abstract BasicContract.Presenter basicPresenter(BasicPresenter presenter);

@FragmentChildScoped
@Binds
abstract BasicContract.View basicView(SignupBasicChildFragment loginFragment);
}
```

This is my interface, which is to be injected from SignupBasicChildFragment into SignupMainFragment,

```
public interface BasicSignUp
{
    void signUpValidateBasic();
}
```